# Ctrl+Mousewheel zoom not working anymore (WPF Designer)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, zooming, designer

For some reason, the Ctrl+Mousewheel shortcut to zoom in the WPF Designer doesn't work since I reinstalled my computer. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 Community Edition. There seems to be no option in the settings menu to control Zoom. I have ReSharper installed (if that is of any importance).

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate + Respharper and it is working. However, note that when you open designer and try to use Ctrl+Mouse wheel it is not working until you click into designer surface. You need to focus designer in order to get it working

Comment: @Liero Yeah, I'm focusing the designer, but it won't zoom. Code (XAML and C#-code alike) does get zoomed with Ctrl+Mouse though.

Comment: Is the designer interactive? I mean, can you select elements in designer?

Comment: @Liero Yes, I can work with the designer perfectly, I can select, add, remove, add columns, resize... anything but not zoom in. I've been using it for months without issue, and only today noticed that I can't zoom in.

Comment: Try shorcuts CTRL+ALT+= and CTRL+ALT+- if they works in xaml designer when it is focused. (The shortcuts may be customized, so check Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->Design.ZoomIn, DesignZoomOut

Comment: @Liero This is weird. I looked in the options, and Zoom is clearly assigned as Ctrl+Alt+Plus and Minus, but when I press them in the designer, they do nothing!

Comment: - Does the zooming work in other platforms?
- Can you set the zoom level using the box at the bottom of the designer?

Trying this out in Community right now :)

Comment: @eyebraus The box works perfectly. It's just the keyboard and mouse shortcuts, which don't work.

Comment: I haven't seen this happen in Community edition yet... I'll try this out with ReSharper installed as well. Do you know if this problem goes away without ReSharper installed?

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Comment: @LukeW It's working fine now after installing Visual Studio 2015.